# Declaring Query Objects in PHP Class Methods

Tags: php, database-abstraction

I am in the process of building an object-oriented forms system. I am putting together a User class which contains about eight functions. Each function contains a MySQL query for which an object of the Query class must be instantiated.

Is there any way to keep from having to declare a new object every single time? It occurs to me that might bog down the server at some point.

The role of the User class is to extract information about the user from the database (name, email, etc). That data is then used throughout the system including to authenticate roles. Here is the User class:

```
class User{

protected $user_id; 
protected $session_hash;

protected $user_username;
protected $user_email;
protected $user_role_id;
protected $user_role_name;

protected $user_first_name;
protected $user_last_name;

public function __construct($user_id, $session_hash){
    $this->user_id = $user_id;
    $this->session_hash = $session_hash;
}   

public function __get($name){
    return $this->name; 
}

public function __set($name, $value){
    $this->$name = $value;
}

public function getLoggedUserInfo(){
    global $db;
    $query = new Query($db->link);

    if($user_matches = $query->select("SELECT name, mail FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX.".d7_users WHERE uid = '".$this->user_id."'")){
        $this->user_username = $user_matches[0]['name'];
        $this->user_email = $user_matches[0]['mail'];

        $this->user_role_id = $this->getLoggedUserRoleId($this->user_id);
        $this->user_role_name = $this->getLoggedUserRoleName($this->user_role_id);
        $this->user_first_name = $this->getLoggedUserFirstName($this->user_id);
        $this->user_last_name = $this->getLoggedUserLastName($this->user_id);

        $user_information_arr = array(
                                'user_id' => $this->user_id,
                                'user_username' => $this->user_username,
                                'user_first_name' => $this->user_first_name,
                                'user_last_name' => $this->user_last_name,
                                'user_email' => $this->user_email,
                                'user_role_id' => $this->user_role_id,
                                'user_role_name' => $this->user_role_name,
                            );

        return $user_information_arr;
    } 
    return false;   
}

private function getLoggedUserRoleId($user_id){
    global $db;
    $query = new Query($db->link);

    if($role_id_matches = $query->select("SELECT rid FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX.".d7_users_roles WHERE uid= '".$user_id."'")){
        $this->user_role_id = $role_id_matches[0]['rid'];
        return $this->user_role_id;
    } 
    return false;   
}

private function getLoggedUserRoleName($role_id){
    global $db;
    $query = new Query($db->link);

    if($role_name_matches = $query->select("SELECT name FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX.".d7_role WHERE rid = '".$role_id."'")){
        return $role_name_matches[0]['name'];
    } 
    return false;   
}

private function getLoggedUserFirstName($user_id){
    global $db;
    $query = new Query($db->link);

    if($first_name_matches = $query->select("SELECT field_first_name_value FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX.".d7_field_revision_field_first_name WHERE entity_id='".$user_id."'")){
        return $first_name_matches[0]['field_first_name_value'];
    } 
    return false;       
}

private function getLoggedUserLastName($user_id){
    global $db;
    $query = new Query($db->link);

    if($last_name_matches = $query->select("SELECT field_last_name_value FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX.".d7_field_revision_field_last_name WHERE entity_id='".$user_id."'")){
        return $last_name_matches[0]['field_last_name_value'];
    } 
    return false;       
}
```

}

Comment: You could pass the Query object into the constructor of your User class and store it as a property of the class. Instantiating the query object in the constructor is also an option, but is less desirable, since you are then coupling your User class and Query class. It would help to more fully understand the role of your User class.

Comment: What you have there is completely unrelated to OOP.

Comment: Drumbeg I think your first solution works best where I just pass the query object and store it as a class property. I'd rather keep the User and Query classes separate. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Pass the query object from an existing instance into the constructor of the User class.

```
protected $queryObject;

public function __construct($user_id, $session_hash, Query $query = NULL){
    $this->user_id = $user_id;
    $this->session_hash = $session_hash;
    $this->queryObject = $query;
}
```